# call a ajax inside an xhr inside a for loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to call an ajax inside a loop xhr request but the ajax results only yields me the last one..or just once..

```
$("#txtArea").contents().find('img').each(function () {
            ctr++;
            xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', $(this).attr("src"), true);

            xhr.responseType = 'blob';

            xhr.onload = function (e) {
                if (this.status == 200) {
                    var blob = this.response;
                    var reader = new window.FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
                    reader.onloadend = function() {
                        base64data = reader.result;


                        console.log("cheweee");

                    base64ToImage(base64data, ctr);  <<--this is the ajax call

                    }


                }

            };
```

here is the ajax

```
function base64ToImage(base64data,ctr) {

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "ConvertB64",
        async: false,
        data: {
            base64datastring: base64data, imgctr: ctr
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })

        .done(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        });
}
```

so what i'm trying to do is..I'm converting an object url to blob then pass that blob to be converted into image then i return the image location for my img tag.

on the xhr side I am able to get the blob data fine but the conversion to image happens only once. and its the last blob.

im using mvc. and I tried creating a arrayed xhr like this xhr[ctr] and I also added asynch: false.

thanks

Comment: Thank you for mentioning what you've tried.  Do you see the "cheweee" console.log for each item in the loop?

Comment: yeh..blob and chewee came out twice.i fix it..its the filename..so what I did was assign a guid per file name coz assigning combine datehrsec plus ctr will not work..thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your `ctr` variable is being shared by all renditions of the loop and is equal to the final value in that loop always.  Try using the index passed into the `.each()` function instead:

```
$("#txtArea").contents().find('img').each(function (i) {
    ...
    ...
    base64ToImage(base64data, i+1); //index starts with 0 so adding 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the first ajax request synchronous and check.....since you are sending multiple ajax requests simultaneously the response is not ordered and that could be the issue